# Android Studio & Firebase databse issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database look like this

[image]

My name is Anand ,and i created an app and i used bottom navigation.3 fragments are used, in one i used to display courses (pdf files).i want to display only particular courses to particular user,means when a user registering they force to select course. According to Course name  they selected they have to get that particular pdf file only .According to my current code it shows everything and i required only to show  according to the course name and users course  .my code mentioned below

enter code here

```
public class CourseFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
//the listview
ListView listView;

//database reference to get uploads data
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

//list to store uploads data
List<Upload> uploadList;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_course_fragment, null);

    uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) v. findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final  WebView webView= (WebView) v. findViewById(R.id.webview);

       //adding a clicklistener on listview
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               //getting the upload
               Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

               //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
               startActivity(intent);

           }
       });


    //getting the database reference
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //retrieving upload data from firebase database
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);
            }

            String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
            }

            //displaying it to list
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: So you want to display all courses where the property name is set to somethig, let say `Hmjbj`? Please also reponde with @AlexMamo

Comment: For example here "Anand" Logged in. Then Only Course named "B" should populate in Fragment not  "Hmjbj" this one  @AlexMamo

Comment: For example here "Anand" Logged in. Then Only Course named "B" should populate in Fragment not "Hmjbj" this one @PradyumanDixit

Comment: @AnandSagar So basically you want to get the value of the `course` property within `Anand` user and search the courses after `B` and get the url of the course. Am i understanding right?

Comment: @AlexMamo if I logged in as "Anand" then I should see only particular course mentioned in  Course Table . for example Anand should see only Course "B"

Comment: Please also don't forget the delete all your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query usersQuery = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("ANAND");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String course = ds.child("course").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, course);

            Query courseRef = rootRef.child("Course").orderByChild("name").equalTo(course);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = ds.child("url").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, name + " / " + url);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            courseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The logic behind this query is the following, first we query the database to find the user with the name `ANAND`, then get the corresponding course name. Having the course name, we can query the database to get corresponding url/name of the corresponding course. So in this case, the output in the logcat will be:

```
B / https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...
```

Comment: Comments [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191056/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-android-studio-firebase-databse-issue).